# Linking a Provided Interface to a definition in Sparx Enterprise Architect (EA)

Tags: components, uml, modeling, software-design, enterprise-architect

I defined my software system using EA. I stayed mainly at the high level so far. The software interfaces between my components are represented as Structural Elements "**Provided Interface**" (the little purple bullets) and "**Required Interface**" (the little sockets).

Now, I would like to go a little bit further into the details, and define the **API** corresponding to each of these Provided Interfaces, ideally as a class diagram. It would be perfect if I were able to create a **nested composite structure diagram** for each of these Provided Interfaces, like for software components for example. But it seems that EA does not enable that.

What I do is that I create an Interface nested in my software component, then I **link** the Required Interface (the purple bullet) to my Interface (purple square) with a **Dependency** link. Then I can create a nested composite structure diagram in my Interface. But I doubt this is the optimal method.

Can someone tell me what is the "EA-approved" way of defining Required Interfaces ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can directly select the `Interface` in the `ProvidedInterface` or `RequiredInterface` without needing to explicitly create a `Realize` or `Dependency` connector to the target interface.

You can do this as shown in the figures below:
[image: Components providing and requiring an Interface]

[image: Selecting an Interface for a ProvidedInterface]

[image: Selecting an Interface for a ProvidedInterface]

One advantage of this is that you do not have to show the actual target interface on the same diagram as the components while still being able to navigate to them. This becomes handy when you have components that provide or require many interfaces (and you do not want to clutter your diagram). With this approach you can use the `Find` | `Locate Classifier in Project Browser` context menu and directly jump to the composite diagram.

[image: Find | Locate Classifier in Project Browser]

[image: Target Interface with Composite Diagram in Project Browser]